# Postgresql 'main/pg_notify/0000': Stale NFS file handle

Tags: linux, postgresql, lvm, jfs

I have a Debian Wheezy computer running a Postgresql Server and NO NFS filesystems.

After rebooting the computer, the following error has appeared:

```
ls: cannot access 0000: Stale NFS file handle
516439 drwx------ 2 postgres postgres    8 Nov 12 20:25 .
516480 drwx------ 3 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 17 17:08 ..
? ?????????? ? ?        ?           ?            ? 0000
```

The "/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_notify/0000" file is STALE and I cannot remove it or do anything at all with it. In order to get rid of that file, I tried the following options:

1. Rebooting the computer in order to unmount the filesystem (as suggested in several forums) did not work.
2. Removing postgresql (apt-get -purge) did not do anything at all either.
3. Trying to manually remove that file does not work either (Stale NFS file handle).

This directory is part of a JFS partition over a ciphered volume managed by LVM.

The output for the fsck:

```
fsck.jfs version 1.1.15, 04-Mar-2011
processing started: 11/17/2014 20:22:30
Using default parameter: -p
The current device is:  /
ujfs_rw_diskblocks: read 0 of 4096 bytes at offset 32768
ujfs_rw_diskblocks: read 0 of 4096 bytes at offset 61440
Superblock is corrupt and cannot be repaired 
since both primary and secondary copies are corrupt.
```

Output for ls -l:

```
ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_notify/0000
```

I would like to know...

1. Why do I have a problem with a NFS handle in a non-NFS partition?
2. Is there anyway in which I can get rid of that file (workarounds are more than welcome as well)?

Comment: Before you do anything else, read and act on https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Comment: Seems exceedingly likely to be filesystem corruption. Why would you use JFS? Please show output of `mount` (without arguments), `ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_notify/0000`, recent output of `dmesg`.

Comment: ls: cannot access /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_notify/0000: Stale NFS file handle

Comment: dmesg does not show any error about the filesystem.

Comment: So, do you have a copy of the data directory taken while the PostgreSQL server was stopped stashed somewhere safe yet? If you don't, *go do that now*.

Comment: @CraigRinger, thanks for the advice, but this is a server that I use for developing my web applications. I do not really need to keep the data. The only problem that I have right now is that I cannot reinstall postgresql since the package has to be configured over the same directory that right now cannot be used.

Comment: Better to edit the question then comment when the edit's done, it's hard to read things like that in comments where there's no formatting. If the data isn't important I suggest simply tearing the system down and recreating it - preferably with a more typical file system like ext4.

Comment: Please, as @CraigRinger asked, show the output of `mount`. Show the contents of `/etc/fstab` file too.

Comment: If your server is intended for "developing your web applications" (not for production purposes), why did you need to use a ciphered logical volume?

Comment: Because it is the laptop they gave me where I work and I also use it for storing my personal stuff. @Jdamian, I do not think that your question helps in solving this problem.